# Is there a better alternative to sudoedit?

Tags: emacs, sudoedit

What I really hate about `sudoedit` is the fact that it always uses a different filename. I'm using `emacsclient` and when editing a file twice I'm left with two useless buffers. Sometimes I even happen to edit the "stale" file.

Is there something like `sudoedit` which uses always the same filename, ideally one the user could choose?

I'm thinking about writing a script allowing me to edit e.g. `/etc/fstab` by editing `$HOME/global/etc/fstab` instead, but I see some problems with keeping the files in sync and also possible security issues (which aren't that important on my single user machine).

Comment: Not sure about an answer to the question in the subject, but if you're after an Emacs solution, [have a look here, SO's "*Open a file with su/sudo inside Emacs*" has some information on how **tramp** can do that.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/95631/993018)

Comment: Good to know. However, I don't really like it: 1. Tramp ignores numpad keys when reading the password. 2. The backup files get written as `~/%backup%~`. 3. I'd really prefer saving a copy somewhere in my home directory for future reference, possibly versioning, and future re-installs.